How to restrict worksheet deletion in excel using office js
I want to restrict delete worksheet option from worksheet tab.
I couldn't find any thing about this so that I use one event which is available in office-js documentation. onDeleted
For that I use this code snippet.
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheetDelete = sheets.onDeleted.add(onSheetDeleted);
    await context.sync();
});

But this event trigger after deletion of worksheet. Based on my  requirement I want to restrict this for some user.
So is there any way I can retrieve last deleted worksheet in this event Or Is there other event which is trigger before deletion of any worksheet so that I use that event so worksheet will not be delete.

you can use the sheet protection office JS Excel function be this is helpful for you. when your sheet is protected then you are not able to add or delete the sheet.
async function protectWorkbookStructure() { 
    await Excel.run(async (context) => { 
        let workbook = context.workbook;
        workbook.load("protection/protected");
        await context.sync();

        if (!workbook.protection.protected) {
            workbook.protection.protect(); 
        } 
    });
}

async function unprotectWorkbookStructure() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        let workbook = context.workbook;
        workbook.protection.unprotect();
    });
}


I already have Worksheet level Protection .If worksheet is locked by login user then I want  that user can delete that worksheet. So I guess Workbook level Protection doesn't help me here(other worksheet can locked by other user) although excel only support workbook level protection for deleting worksheet.
